# Why does adding an instruction that is never executed lead to lower performance in my code?

Tags: c++, performance

***Background:***

I'm writing a lock-free stack, and I'm working on optimizing it.

I found that adding sleeps after missed compare_and_exchange operations results in much higher throughput when testing under highly concurrent scenarios:

```
void stack::push(node* n)
{
    node old_head, new_head{ n };
    n->n_ = nullptr;

    if (head_.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, new_head))
        return;

    for (;;)
    {
        n->n_ = old_head.n_;
        new_head.create_id(old_head);
        if (head_.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, new_head))
            return;

        // testing conditions _never_ reach here, so why does this line make the program slower??
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(5));

        // debug break is used to confirm execution never reaches here
        __debugbreak();
    }
}
```

[(The full code can be found here on GitHub.)](https://github.com/MGaz/performance_question_lfs)

I sleep after compare_exchange fails twice - the first one is effectively a load(), except when the stack is empty. Sounds good right? That's an easy optimization. But...

***Here's what I did not expect:***

Adding the sleep code results in significantly lower throughput in scenarios that will *never* run the sleep code! This is confirmed by adding the __debugbreak.

Example numbers:

```
test conditions:
----------------------
data_count = 1
loop_count = 100000000
thread_count = 1


sleep code commented out
-------------------------------
operations per second: 75357000
operations per second: 74487000
operations per second: 74571000
operations per second: 75357000
operations per second: 75843000
operations per second: 74183000
operations per second: 74822000
operations per second: 74321000
operations per second: 75301000
operations per second: 73991000

with sleep code
-------------------------------
operations per second: 60716000
operations per second: 61031000
operations per second: 61236000
operations per second: 60957000
operations per second: 60808000
operations per second: 60642000
operations per second: 60734000
operations per second: 60661000
operations per second: 60422000
operations per second: 61162000
```

This was with the latest version of Xcode 5. I see a similar difference in numbers when using Visual Studio 2013 as well.

**So, what's happening here? Why does the code show significantly lower numbers when adding something in that is never executed?**

Comment: You're putting code that *could* be reached inside a `for` loop. This can cause the number of optimizations that the compiler can perform on that loop to change pretty drastically.

Comment: Can you add an annotation to the condition that it is most likely true and retest? I think the issue is branch mis-prediction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902

Comment: This the principle of "there is no free lunch" at work.  With the sleep_for() in place, the function gets too big to still be inlined.  You can fix it in VS by putting `__forceinline` attribute before the function.  Xcode probably uses `__attribute__((always_inline))`.  That doesn't necessarily improve the overall perf of a real program however, YMMV.

Comment: Without seeing the generated code this is just guesswork.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I was under the impression that branch prediction would optimize for true, and for the same result? I don't see this as a likely branch mis-prediction, but I'm open to understanding how this one would be.

Comment: @HansPassant - the code was originally in a separate cpp file where (afaik) it couldn't be inlined. I only brought it all into one file to show the test.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the sleep adds another branch.
Without the sleep, there will be a jump back to the top of the loop if compare_exchange_weak is false.
With the sleep, there will be a branch to the function epilogue if compare_exchange_weak is true, and an unconditional jump back to the top of the loop after the sleep.